# custom ui autocomplete edit to url

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i want to edit this code please:

the original code: (taken from http://designshack.net/?p=40354 )

```
$(function(){
var currencies = [
{ value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
{ value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
{ value: 'Algerian dinar', data: 'DZD' },
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
lookup: currencies,
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.value +'<br> <strong>Symbol:</strong> ' + suggestion.data;
$('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
}
});
});
```

my edited code looks like:

```
$(function(){
var mydata = [
{ value: 'google exmple', url: 'http://google.com/' },
{ value: 'yahoo exmple', url: 'http://yahoo.com/' },
{ value: 'bing exmple', url: 'http://bing.com/' },
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({

// edit here
// i want that when i click on suggestion = redirect me to url
// and the maximum number of suggestion that shown = 7

});
});
```

thanks.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please

Comment: Did you try something in place of `// edit here` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example you can simply redirect to the site on select. There does not seem to be any way to set the results limit.

```
var mydata = [
  { value: 'google exmple', url: 'http://google.com/' },
  { value: 'yahoo exmple', url: 'http://yahoo.com/' },
  { value: 'bing exmple', url: 'http://bing.com/' },
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  lookup: mydata,
  onSelect: function(data) {
    window.location.href = data.url;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({

    lookup: mydata,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
      window.location.href = suggestion.url;
    }

});
```